# Registry auditing for disconnected users

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-registry

What I would like to get is Windows events for registry changes. Now, I found [this](https://betanews.com/2015/11/18/how-to-monitor-registry-changes/) manual where in one of the steps of setting the events, the audit configuration of the registry key must be edited (find the key -> right click -> permissions -> advanced -> audit).

Now, say I want to set this monitoring for the branch:

> HKCU\Software\Classes

I must find all the regular users under `HKU` and set the auditing for every one of them, the thing is that the user data is loaded only when it is [logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431367/hkey-users-contains-only-logged-in-users). I can load the registry key manually and add the auditing with:

```
reg load HKU\Steven C:\Users\Steven\ntuser.dat
```

But the problem is that not all keys are available there (for instance Classes is not available), and to be honest, it seems like a crude solution. Plus there is the dilemma of what happens if a user is added after the installation?

On a Windows 10, is there any way to add auditing configurations for all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user first logs on and their profile folder is created, their user hive is initialized as a copy of the default user hive, stored here:

```
C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT
```

After the profile is created, the copies are independent, so there is no convenient way to edit all users' profiles in one shot. If, however, you [load and edit that hive](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-can-i-configure-default-settings-new-users), the changes will be reflected in any subsequently created profiles.

The `Classes` key is stored in a separate hive that you can load and edit separately:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat
```

Unfortunately, there is no default classes hive; it appears to be initialized to an empty hive when a profile is created.

---

To make dealing with all this a little less tedious for you, I wrote a PowerShell script to an audit rule on each of the given subtrees loaded under `HKEY_USERS`. But first, we need to enable the auditing privilege, which requries a surprising amount of code (adapted from [Lee Holmes](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/09/24/adjusting-token-privileges-in-powershell/)):

```
param(    
    ## The privilege to adjust.
    $Privilege,
    ## The process on which to adjust the privilege. Defaults to the current process.
    $ProcessId = $pid,
    ## Switch to disable the privilege, rather than enable it.
    [Switch] $Disable
)

## Taken from P/Invoke.NET with minor adjustments.
$definition = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class AdjPriv
{

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
    ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]

    internal struct TokPriv1Luid
    {
        public int Count;
        public long Luid;
        public int Attr;
    }

    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
    internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
    internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;

    public static bool EnablePrivilege(long processHandle, string privilege, bool disable)
    {
        bool retVal;
        TokPriv1Luid tp;
        IntPtr hproc = new IntPtr(processHandle);
        IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
        retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
        tp.Count = 1;
        tp.Luid = 0;

        if(disable)
        {
            tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
        }
        else
        {
            tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        }

        retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
        retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        return retVal;
    }
}

'@

$processHandle = (Get-Process -id $ProcessId).Handle
try { 
  Add-Type $definition 
} catch {} # Silent failure on re-registration

[AdjPriv]::EnablePrivilege($processHandle, $Privilege, $Disable)
```

Save that as `privs.ps1`. Then we can use it in our script, which should go in the same directory:

```
Param (
    [string[]]$Subkeys
)
$rights = 'ChangePermissions,CreateSubKey,CreateLink,Delete,SetValue,TakeOwnership'
.\privs.ps1 -Privilege SeSecurityPrivilege
$users = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey('Users', 'Default')
$Subkeys | % {
    $key = $users.OpenSubKey($_, $true)
    $acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
    $rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule]::new([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new('Everyone'), $rights, 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Success')
    $acl.AddAuditRule($rule)
    $key.SetAccessControl($acl)
    $key.Close()
}
```

For each of the provided subkeys, it creates an rule that audits successful changes (defined by the `$rights` variable near the top, which you can change) in that key or subkeys. Save it as a PS1 file, e.g. `regaudit.ps1`. If you haven't already, enable PowerShell script execution as directed in [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info). Then load all necessary hives under `HKEY_USERS`. You can run the script from an elevated PowerShell prompt like so:

```
.\regaudit.ps1 -Subkeys 'Steven\Control Panel', 'Steven\Software\Microsoft'
```

Note that you should not include `HKCU` or any such root. You can pass as many subkeys as you like. Alternatively, you can create a text file with one subkey per line and use that like so:

```
.\regaudit.ps1 -Subkeys (gc .\toaudit.txt)
```

**N.B.** Audit events will not appear in the Security log unless "Audit object access" is enabled in the Audit Policy section of the Local Security Policy.

Further reading: [Access Control in .NET](http://www.michaeltaylorp3.net/access-control-in-net/)